# Clicking "automatically move this discussion to chat?" does not preserve unsubmitted comment text

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

Today is the first time I encountered "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to [automatically move this discussion to chat?](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6172/discussion-between-aculich-and-eyquem)", but I had already started typing the text of my comment. Instead of submitting I thought it would be good to follow the advice and start a chat instead of posting another comment. Unfortunately the text I had typed (but not yet submitted) was not copied over to the chat discussion and I lost it because I had not copied the text before hitting the link.

A better behavior for the UI in this case would be to automatically put the unsubmitted comment text into the text box in the discussion window so I could have continued editing it or submitted it. Instead I have to type it all over again. Not a big deal, but this would be a nice little bit of polish that would be helpful for people new to the chat feature.

At very least it should follow the convention on other sites that detect unsaved changes and warn before navigating away that data could be lost.

I would consider this a bug, but I tagged this question as both a `bug` and a `feature-request`.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a bug... one would never expect clicking a link to somehow preserve unsubmitted form values. I don't even think it's all that useful a feature to request, to be honest... but it's definitely not  a bug. I see that tag has been removed, anyway :)

Comment: I wonder consider behavior that results in lost data to be an undesirable feature... though the impact is small, from a user-perspective I still consider it a bug myself. At very least it should follow the convention on other sites that detect unsaved changes and warn before navigating away that data could be lost. In this case it is a small amount of data and this should probably be considered a low-priority feature, but still worth thinking about since it could be written as a general solution for preserving unsaved data in text entry boxes in other areas of the site, as well.

Comment: As I said; new feature, sure. Good, useful feature? Perhaps, yes. Bug? Definitely not, IMO.